# PyTorch: a very simple model is not trained

Tags: pytorch

I am watching a tutorial on youtube called [PyTorch for Deep Learning & Machine Learning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_xro1bcAuA).

I've tried to build a very simple linear regression model based on information on the video. Below is code with the model and training loop. I also provided outputs.

For some reason, the model is not getting trained. I assigned parameters to an optimiser, created a loss function, then backpropagate, and finally update parameters with `step()`. As you can see from output, the loss has quite odd values. I can't understand why it is not working.

```py
# Imports
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch import optim


# Create model class
class LinearRegressionModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear_layer = nn.Linear(in_features=1, out_features=1)
        
    # Forward method to define the computation in the model
    def forward(self, X: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return self.linear_layer(X)

    
# Set manual seed
torch.manual_seed(42)

# Create data
weight, bias = 0.7, 0.3
start, end, step = 0, 1, 0.02
X = torch.arange(start, end, step).unsqueeze(dim=1)
y = weight*X + bias + 0.035*torch.randn_like(X) 

# Create train/test split
train_split = int(0.8*len(X))
X_train, y_train = X[:train_split], y[:train_split]
X_test,  y_test  = X[train_split:], y[train_split:]

# Create model
model = LinearRegressionModel()
print(model, end="\n\n")
print(model.state_dict(), end="\n\n")

# Create loss function
loss_fn = nn.L1Loss()

# Create optimiser
optimiser = optim.SGD(params=model.parameters(), lr=1e2)

# Training loop 
epochs = 200
for epoch in range(1, epochs+1):
    # Set model to training mode
    model.train()
    
    # Forward pass
    y_pred = model(X_train)
    
    # Calculate loss
    loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_train)
    
    # Zero gradients in optimiser
    optimiser.zero_grad()
    
    # Backpropate
    loss.backward()
    
    # Step model's lparameters
    optimiser.step()
    
    ### Evaluate the current state
    model.eval()
    with torch.inference_mode():
        test_pred = model(X_test)
        test_loss = loss_fn(test_pred, y_test)
    
    # Print the current state
    if epoch == 1 or epoch % 10 == 0:
        print("Epoch: {:3} | Loss: {:.2f} | Test loss {:.2f}".format(epoch,loss,test_loss))

print()
print(model.state_dict())
```

The output:

```py
LinearRegressionModel(
  (linear_layer): Linear(in_features=1, out_features=1, bias=True)
)

OrderedDict([('linear_layer.weight', tensor([[0.8294]])), ('linear_layer.bias', tensor([-0.5927]))])

Epoch:   1 | Loss: 0.85 | Test loss: 133.93
Epoch:  10 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch:  20 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch:  30 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch:  40 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch:  50 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch:  60 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch:  70 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch:  80 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch:  90 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch: 100 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch: 110 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch: 120 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch: 130 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch: 140 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch: 150 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch: 160 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch: 170 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch: 180 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch: 190 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78
Epoch: 200 | Loss: 114.36 | Test loss: 0.78

OrderedDict([('linear_layer.weight', tensor([[0.8294]])), ('linear_layer.bias', tensor([-0.5927]))])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this works well; you just need to make the changes in:

1. **Learning rate**: Your learning rate is very high, so replace its value with some smaller value; here, I've used `lr=1e-2`.

   ```py
   optimiser = optim.SGD(params=model.parameters(), lr=1e-2)
   ```

I got the following output:

```py
LinearRegressionModel(
  (linear_layer): Linear(in_features=1, out_features=1, bias=True)
)

OrderedDict([('linear_layer.weight', tensor([[0.8294]])), ('linear_layer.bias', tensor([-0.5927]))])

Epoch:   1 | Loss: 0.85 | Test loss 0.77
Epoch:  10 | Loss: 0.74 | Test loss 0.64
Epoch:  20 | Loss: 0.63 | Test loss 0.51
Epoch:  30 | Loss: 0.51 | Test loss 0.37
Epoch:  40 | Loss: 0.40 | Test loss 0.24
Epoch:  50 | Loss: 0.28 | Test loss 0.11
Epoch:  60 | Loss: 0.17 | Test loss 0.04
Epoch:  70 | Loss: 0.10 | Test loss 0.12
Epoch:  80 | Loss: 0.09 | Test loss 0.16
Epoch:  90 | Loss: 0.08 | Test loss 0.18
Epoch: 100 | Loss: 0.07 | Test loss 0.19
Epoch: 110 | Loss: 0.07 | Test loss 0.18
Epoch: 120 | Loss: 0.07 | Test loss 0.18
Epoch: 130 | Loss: 0.06 | Test loss 0.17
Epoch: 140 | Loss: 0.06 | Test loss 0.16
Epoch: 150 | Loss: 0.06 | Test loss 0.15
Epoch: 160 | Loss: 0.06 | Test loss 0.14
Epoch: 170 | Loss: 0.05 | Test loss 0.14
Epoch: 180 | Loss: 0.05 | Test loss 0.13
Epoch: 190 | Loss: 0.05 | Test loss 0.12
Epoch: 200 | Loss: 0.05 | Test loss 0.12

OrderedDict([('linear_layer.weight', tensor([[0.9241]])), ('linear_layer.bias', tensor([0.2178]))])
```

A high learning rate usually skips the optimal value. Therefore, it didn't work earlier.

I hope this helps you. Thanks!

Comment: Oh dear. I kept looking at this code something like 10 times and didn't notice my learning was 100 instead of `0.01`. Thank you.

Comment: Happy it helped you.